# How to Fetch records between two dates in cosmosdb using c# application?

Tags: c#-4.0, azure-cosmosdb

I have tried to get the records between two dates in cosmosdb using C# application. but I couldnt find any article to do that.Please anyone suggest?

Comment: Please include what you've tried with examples and error messages, results. etc.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options.

1. Pass a sql query as a string and use the Between operator
   `= $"SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id BETWEEN '{StartDate.ToString(dateFormat)}' AND '{EndDate.ToString(dateFormat)}'`
2. Or use LINQ in the cosmos client